# PHP - Find number in a string

Tags: php, string, search, numbers

I want to get **16** from this string :

`request id is 16 (group id 1) for host localhost`

And the Status message of JID No. **10** (which is in this case `Kill time expired`)

```
JID  Pri S  Owner Number       Pages Dials      Status
11   127 D   root 0xxxxxx     1:1   1:12         
16   116 F www-da 0xxxxxx     0:1  12:12         No carrier detected; too 
15   127 D   root 0xxxxxx     1:1   1:12         
10   127 F   root 0xxxxxx     0:0   0:12         Kill time expired
9    127 F   root 0xxxxxx     0:0   0:12         Job aborted by request
8    127 F   root 0xxxxxx     0:0   0:12         Job aborted by request
```

**EDIT** : I managed to solve the first problem. the answer is `(\d+)`. I need a hint for the second search.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), where are you stuck?

Comment: @deceze I tried and searched many things online but couldn't find a way to get such number from a string. The only thing which was closest was strip all numbers from a string. which in this case, there is 2 numbers and I only need the first one.

Comment: Then sorry, but you have not tried hard enough. You could even cobble something together using `substr`. Have you looked into regular expressions?

Comment: @deceze the only thing I can guess, is finding the position of first `(` and strip number from beginning to that position. And second search (status of JID) is the hardest

Comment: Have you considered regexes? http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is a great place to learn & test

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Thanks a lot. very nice tool. I will look into it and answer back when I found the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second one, you could look for a line that starts with "10", then "something" and then 9 consecutive spaces. After the spaces is what you need to capture. The regex is `^10.+\s{9}(.*)`

Comment: Thanks! But you forgot to add `\\` before s. Looking for a line that starts with the number was a better approach. I was struggling for some weird ways.