# PHP : Preserve the output formatting of System()

Tags: php, formatting, system

How can I get the output of a command like it shows on console ?

```
<?php
ob_start();
system('faxstat -s' , $retval);
$last_line = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
preg_match('/^32.+\s{9}(.*)/m', $last_line, $job_id);
?>
```

In console, the output is like :

```
JID  Pri S  Owner Number       Pages Dials     TTS Status
36   127 R www-da 0xxxxxxxx     0:1   0:12         
32   127 R www-da 0xxxxxxxx     0:1   0:12         
35   127 R www-da 0xxxxxxxx     0:1   0:12
```

But in PHP, the echo of `$last_line` is like :

> JID  Pri S  Owner Number       Pages Dials     TTS Status 36   127 R
>   www-da 0xxxxxxxx     0:1   0:12          32   127 R www-da 0xxxxxxxx
>   0:1   0:12          35   127 R www-da 0xxxxxxxx     0:1   0:12

**Note:** I don't want to print the output, So no need for `<pre>` tag. I want to `preg_match` it. Because it loses the formatting, my regex is useless.

Comment: If you PRE it out or just look at the source of the html page, it is not correctly formatted? It should, in HTML output, it's normal spaces are not kept, but i'd be surprised that in memory they are lost...

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin It does look like it If I use `<Pre>` for printing. But it's not exactly the same and my goal is not print the output.

Comment: it's ok it you don't want to print it out, but i'm trying to make sure it is indeed different. I think that you see something different because the TABS are used and in the console show a different output than with PRE. If you str_replace("\t", "zzzzz") just to make sure, tell me then you see ZZZZ in your output. If it is the case, you might now know why you have trouble with your regex

Comment: I cannot reproduce 'loss of formatting' here. I can only assume you are looking at it in a browser which _will_ remove the formatting.

Comment: same here, besides it's a lot of work to do it via ob_*, couldn't you just use $string = shell_exec(*your_command*) ?

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Tried that and didn't find any zzzzz anywhere.

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof I did try `exec()` but not `shell_exec`. `exec` has same results. let me check shell_exec.

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof Same results with `shell_exec`.

Comment: so if you use exec with an array by reference, it returns an array with only 1 element? or do you use $ouput = exec(*command*)?

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof I used it like `$output = exec(command)`. Is there any difference ?

Comment: yes, that only returns the last line. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php  use exec(*command*,$output);  $ouput will become an array filled with the lines

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof Thanks. That totally solved the problem. I don't need for regex anymore too. This was exactly my goal, but still the problem on formatting hasn't solved. How should I handle the accepted answer ?

Comment: I would use `preg_split('/\s+/', $line)` to split on whitespace characters. Then you could reference each column by number.

Comment: @RobertK That is a possible solution, But still it's hard to find the exact JID and status word. The output really doesn't have a proper pattern to follow. There could be some wrong results returned.

Comment: I'll post a pattern below that works fine for me given your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) with a  variable that's passed to it by reference to capture your outputlines.

```
$lastLine = exec('df -h',$output);
```

exec only returns the last line it encouters as it's return value, you'll find the complete output of the command exec executed in your $output parameter (the variable you provided [by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) which exec() transforms into an array and fills up, See also [PHP: References Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php))

e.g.

```
<?php
$lastLine = exec('df -h',$output);

print "\n$lastLine\n";
print_r($output);
```

will print

```
none                  990M     0  990M   0% /var/lock

Array
(
    [0] => Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    [1] => /dev/sda1             145G  140G  5.8G  97% /
    [2] => none                  981M  668K  980M   1% /dev
    [3] => none                  990M  3.4M  986M   1% /dev/shm
    [4] => none                  990M  240K  989M   1% /var/run
    [5] => none                  990M     0  990M   0% /var/lock
)
```

So as you can see $lastLine really is the very last line the command printed

I do not understand why shell_exec or the backticks do not work for you though, sorry.

Now for your parsing pattern:

```
<?php

// was stil using your posted 'wrong output'
$output = "JID Pri S Owner Number Pages Dials TTS Status 36 127 R www-da 0xxxxxxxx 0:1 0:12 32 127 R www-da 0xxxxxxxx 
0:1 0:12 35 127 R www-da 0xxxxxxxx 0:1 0:12";

// we just strip the header out
$header = "JID Pri S Owner Number Pages Dials TTS Status ";

$headerless = str_replace($header,'',$output);

$pattern = '/([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([A-Z]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([0-9:]+)\s+([0-9:]+)/m'; // m to let it traverse multi-line

/*
  we match on 0-9 whitespace 0-9 WS A-Z 'Anything not WS' WS ANWS WS 0-9:0-9 WS 0-9:0-9
*/
preg_match_all($pattern,$headerless,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

this will give you all the individual elements. Obviously you dont need to strip the header and all that when you've used exec to return it in an array but the pattern should work fine in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a very nice idea to parsing a huge string.

Answer (score 1):

Using the backtick operator (`) should preserve the output formatting.

```
$lastline = `ls`;
```

Comment: This is the same thing. It doesn't preserve anything. Also, I have nothing to do with HTML. I just want to `preg_match` the string and do my job on PHP side.

Comment: system() only returns the very last line, xperator wants to capture all the output

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof Not really. Calling `system` or `exec` or using the backtick operator will give practically identical results. I cannot reproduce his problem.

Comment: the return value of system returns only the very last line, as mentioned in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php Shell_exec (or backtick will return it all, downvote removed)

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof And yet the documentation is wrong for PHP 5.3.8, as it returns all lines; this may have been "fixed" in later versions.

Comment: I read the documentation, it says system return the last line. But I used it in many codes and it is returning all output. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: it's in the docs/specs and on my system (5.3.5) it does return only the last line, so it wouldn't have suited the OP. It might be good to file a bug since the behaviour in 5.3.8 doesn't follow documentation. As long as the docs/specs aren't changed it's not good to trust on it to return anything but the very last line.

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof I see. Then I am going to replace it with exec.

Comment: exec is same thing: last line, you need to give it an array by reference to capture the lines of output http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @RobertK How should I use backtick operator ? I use it but it doesn't even run the command.

Comment: backtick is same as shell_exec but it doesn't work when safe_mode is activated on your server, that might be troubling you.

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof No! `Safe_Mode` is off.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to output anything you can also use `exec()`. However `$last_line` will only contain the actual last line printed by the command. If you want to process the entire output you can redirect it to an array with the second parameter of `exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the regex you're using for your match.  My guess would be that you're trying to match on a non-print character that is not in this converted string.  Try matching on **\s** which will look for several types of white space characters.

Comment: What are you trying to isolate?

Comment: I'm guessing you want a value from the line staring with only 32.  You have a reference to \s{9} which means exactly 9 whitespace chars.  You don't have that in your example system output.  I only count 5 as the biggest piece of whitespace you have in your output.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116345/php-find-number-in-a-string This is what I am trying to get from the output, although my output posted here doesn't have that string.

Comment: Try this regex: `/^(32)\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?(\S*)/m`  ... This will split up the match based on your columns and not the arbitrary white space on the end which seems to be different on your system.  It will also match on a blank line with no output on the last column with a blank value.

Comment: Your expression works till the number part. My goal is getting the status column of that line.

Comment: Try `/.*^(32)\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?\S*\s+?(\S*)$.*/` I think that will suck out just the status of the 32 line and nothing else.

Comment: That doesn't work if there is a text in Status column. Let's get over regex. This requires a lot of times and is not the main topic of this question. Thanks a lot anyway for putting effort :)